# How to use onChange with asyn redux actions?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm having a little bit of headache trying to make a really small form that doesn't have a submit button, using basically `onChange` to make async calls to actions in Redux to save some data.

The problem is that in every key pressed the form is really, really slow. Looks like it's re-rendering and waiting for the response to return to fill the component again.

```
// from redux
const { firstName, lastName, email } = this.props.user

// component
<input
  value={email}
  ref="email"
  placeholder="jonh.doe@gmail.com"
  onChange={_onChange} />

// dispatch
_onChange() {
  const userInfo = this.getUserInfo()
  this.props.dispatch(updateUser(userInfo))
}

//action
const updateUser = (userInfo) => {
  const endpoint = `/api/user/${userInfo.userId}`

  const config = {
    method: 'PUT',
    body: JSON.stringify(userInfo)
  }

 return {
   type: 'UPDATE_USER',
   payload: new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     fetch(endpoint, config)
       .then(response => {
         resolve(userInfo)
       })
       .catch(err => { reject(err) })
   })
  }
}

//reducer
case 'UPDATE_USER_FULFILLED': {
  return {
    ...state,
    fetched: true,
    fetching: false,
    user: {
      firstName: payload.firstName,
      lastName: payload.lastName,
      email: payload.email
    }
  }
}
```

It's also displaying this error in the console:

```
 SettingsComponent is changing a controlled input of type undefined to be uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa).
```

I don't know what to do in this case. 
Any help appreaciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `debounce` function to stop rapid fire requests.

its available in lodash, underscore libraries. if u want a plain javascript version here it is

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};


<input onChange={debounce(_onChange, 250)}
```